# Check ASCII pyspark dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, ascii, user-defined-functions, pyspark

I need to check in a pyspark dataframe if all the values are ASCII, I do that with the following:

```
def is_ascii(s):
  if s:
    return all(ord(c) < 128 for c in s)
  else:
    return None

is_ascii_udf = udf(lambda l: is_ascii(l), BooleanType() )

df_result = df.select( *map(lambda col: is_ascii_udf(df[col]).alias(col),  df.columns ) )
```

I am trying to use this with a new data that has 50MM rows and 9000 columns, and I get this error:

```
ExecutorLostFailure (executor 30 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues.
```

It seems that the memory is full, I cannot get a bigger cluster, so I thougth of doing the following

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df = spark.read.parquet( path)
for i in df.columns:
  df = spark.read.parquet( path)
  df_result = df.select( *map(lambda col: is_ascii_udf(df[col]).alias(col),  [i] ) )
  n = df_result.filter( ~F.col(i) ).count()
  if n>0:
    print(i,n)
```

But I get the same error, why I am still getting the same error if each time I am reading the dataframe and just doing the udf to one column

The cluster has 50 GB of memory, 6 cores, max 8 workers

I think the error is with the function, or how I am using it

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that even running it on one column is too much for your cluster. Anyway, there are Spark SQL methods available for doing what you want, which should be more efficient in terms of both performance and memory.

The code below will give a Boolean, or the count, of non-ascii characters in each column and collect the result into a list.

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')

is_not_ascii = [[col, spark.sql('select max(array_max(transform(split(%s, ""), x -> ascii(x))) >= 128) as is_ascii from df' % col).collect()[0][0]] for col in df.columns]
# e.g. [['key', False], ['val', False]]

count_not_ascii = [[col, spark.sql('select sum(cast(array_max(transform(split(%s, ""), x -> ascii(x))) >= 128 as int)) as is_ascii from df' % col).collect()[0][0]] for col in df.columns]
# e.g. [['key', 0], ['val', 0]]
```